# span across columns with hwrite

Tags: r

Is it possible to span a heading across multiple columns with hwrite (or any other HTML-creating package)? I can sort of fake it with dataframe pieces nested within a larger table, but it's not quite a real span (and it looks ugly).

I did not see a version of this in the [examples](http://www.ebi.ac.uk/~gpau/hwriter/) but maybe there exists elsewhere.

Thanks,
Tom

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Edit: I should add that the `print.xtable` method does html, also (I shouldn't assume that is known). Use the `type = "html"` option.

---

No experience with html, but I do the following with LaTeX.

In the `xtable` package, the `print.xtable` method has an option `add.to.row` that allows you to do just that. For `add.to.row` you add a list-of-lists, where the first list is a list of row numbers and the second list is a list of commands to insert at that spot. From the `?print.xtable`:

> `add.to.row` -- a list of two
>   components. The first component (which
>   should be called 'pos') is a list
>   contains the position of rows on which
>   extra commands should be added at the
>   end, The second component (which
>   should be called 'command') is a
>   character vector of the same length of
>   the first component which contains the
>   command that should be added at the
>   end of the specified rows. Default
>   value is NULL, i.e. do not add
>   commands.

For LaTeX I use the following homemade command that add a "(1)" above the coefficient and t-stat column.

```
my.add.to.row <- function(x) {
    first <- "\\hline \\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & "
    middle <- paste(paste("\\multicolumn{2}{c}{(", seq(x), ")}", sep = ""), collapse = " & ")
    last <- paste("\\\\ \\cline {", 2, "-", 1 + 2 * x, "}", collapse = "")
    string <- paste(first, middle, last, collapse = "")
    list(pos = list(-1), command = string)
}
```

HTH.

Comment: Thanks @richardh, It works! Just to complete this, here is some code for HTML output. 
`library(xtable)
d <- data.frame(x=1:5, y=6:10)
x <- xtable(d)
print(x, type="html", file="d:/delete/test6.htm",include.rownames=F, include.colnames=F,
 add.to.row=list(pos=list(0), command=c("<TR> <TD colspan=2> Numbers </TD>  </TR>")))
`

Answer (score 1):

I can't see an obvious way of generating a table with headers that cross multiple columns.  Here's a really awful hack that might solve your problem though.

1. Generate your table as normal.
2. In the source code for that page, the first row of the table will look something like

   <td someattribute="somevalue">First column name</td><td someattribute="somevalue">Second column name</td>
3. You can read the file into R, either with `htmlTreeParse` from the `XML` package, or plain old `readLines`.
4. Now replace the offending bit of html with the correct value.  The `stringr` package may well help here.

   <td someattribute="somevalue" colspan="2">Column name spanning two columns</td>
5. And write back out to file.

Comment: Thanks, Richie. This was the lugubrious workaround that I thought of as well, except you've spelled out the R commands for it that I didn't know. If I do have to go this route you've saved me a lot of research!